# How to report a possible bug in gij (GNU libgcj) version 5.4.0?

Tags: jvm

I found some possible bugs in gij (GNU libgcj) version 5.4.0, but I did not know where can I report them to the developer?

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

gij version:

```
$ gij -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 5.4.0 20160609

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Here is the package page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcj-jre - This leads to the GCC Launchpad Bug Reports page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bugs